# R : Check whether particular number is in the list

Tags: r, list, for-loop

Here is my situation :

I have a list called **sc**

```
> sc
[[1]]
 [1]  1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46 51 52

[[2]]
 [1]  2  7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47 53 54

[[3]]
 [1]  3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48 55 56

[[4]]
 [1]  4  9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49 57 58

[[5]]
 [1]  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 59 60

[[6]]
[1] 61 62 63 64 65 66
```

then i want to check whether 8 is in which `sc[k] (k=1:6)`.

how to code it? i tried to use for but not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of these should work:

```
sapply(sc, `%in%`, x = 8)
sapply(sc, is.element, el = 8)
mapply(`%in%`, 8, sc)
mapply(is.element, 8, sc)
```

These all return the same vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE`: whether each list element contains `8` or not. If what you want are such indices (`k`) where `8` is found, just wrap it with `which`, for example:

```
which(sapply(sc, `%in%`, x = 8))
```